# Can the Card component take children react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a card component on react native with children, but I keep getting this typescript error

```
(alias) const Card: (React.FunctionComponent<Omit<CardProps & Partial<ThemeProps<CardProps>>, keyof ThemeProps<T>>> | React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<...>) & {
...; }
import Card Type '{ children: Element[]; containerStyle: { marginBottom: number; borderRadius: number; shadowColor: string; shadowOffset: { width: number; height: number; }; shadowOpacity: number; shadowRadius: number; elevation: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps & Partial<ThemeProps<CardProps>>'.


Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps & Partial<ThemeProps<CardProps>>'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my code:

```
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <Card containerStyle={styles.card}>
            <Avatar rounded size='xlarge' source={userprofile} containerStyle={styles.profilePicture} />
            <Card.Title>
                {member.firstname} {member.lastname}
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Divider />
            <Text>
                {member.firstname} {member.lastname} has attended a total of 100 services in the past two years...
            </Text>
        </Card>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show the implementations of the `Card` component too?